# Makefile calling other makefile with target, gives wrong target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with a target clean:

```
clean:
   $(MAKE) -f <other makefile location> clean
```

When I call make clean in this makefile, it tells me that in the other makefile there is no rule 'clean-linux'.  Specifically here is the output.

```
make -f /root/ovaldi-5.5.25-src/project/linux/Makefile clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/ovaldi-5.5.25-src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/ovaldi-5.5.25-src'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'clean-linux'. Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/ovaldi-5.5.25-src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ovaldi-5.5.25-src'
```

Why is it giving it the clean-linux target and not just clean like I specified?

Comment: clean :
 @if [ $(PLATFORM) = LINUX ]; then \
  make clean-linux; \
 fi; \
 if  [ $(PLATFORM) = SUNOS ]; then \
  make clean-sunos; \
 fi;

clean-linux:
 -rm -rf $(OUTDIR)

clean-sunos:
 -rm -rf $(OUTDIR)


It does call clean-linux but that is already specified.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but maybe the 'clean' target in the second makefile calls 'clean-linux'?

Can you post the clean target of the second makefile?

**Edit:**

In light of your posted clean target it seems you're just calling the clean-linux target incorrectly.

[Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta) has posted the correct way of dealing with your problem in their answer so I'm going to +1 that.

Comment: It does call it but it is specified.  It seems as if target dependencies and calls to make in the second makefile call make on the first makefile.

Answer (score 2):

When you make (or $(MAKE)), by default you use whatever makefile is there. So here's what I think is happening.

1. You cd to some location.

   You 'make -f Makefile_A clean'.

   make runs with Makefile_A, and does '$(MAKE) -f Makefile_B clean'.

   make[1] runs with Makefile_B, and does '$(MAKE) clean-linux'.

   make[2] runs with whatever makefile is here which might be anything (I suspect it's Makefile_A) but whatever it is it has no rule for clean-linux.

The solution: rewrite your second makefile (the one that has clean-linux) so that clean-linux becomes a prerequisite of clean (if/when you're on a linux system). That way it won't run make[2].

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), LINUX)
clean: clean-linux
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), SUNOS)
clean: clean-sunos
endif

clean:;
```

Comment: that syntax gives me "missing separator" on the 1st ifeq line

Comment: @gcb, so try some basic troubleshooting. Can you get any `ifeq` statement to work? If the problem persists, post it as a question with your full makefile and details like which version of Make you're using.